# Navigation menu width automatically shortens or spread

Tags: html, css, menu, resize, html-lists

Navigation menu width automatically shortens or spread with the width of the li elements.
My last li element is logged in user, and when the user have username with more letters i want the menu to spread just enough to fit in, and the same when username have less letters.

```
     require_once 'classes/User.php';

     $user = User::getById($_SESSION['user']['uid']);
     ?>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class=><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li class=><a href='add.php'><span>Add</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='test.php'><span>Test</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='help.php'><span>Help</span></a></li>
       <li class="last"><a href='user.php'><span><?php print $user->getUsername()?></span></a>
    <ul>
         <li><a class="settings" href='user.php'><span>Settings</span></a></li>
         <li><a class="adduser" href='useradd.php'><span>Add User</span></a></li>
         <li><a class="logout" href='logout.php'><span>Log Out</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Just don't set fixed widths on the menu elements - that way they'll wrap around the content

Answer (score 0):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bindashsandeep/PLPzC/)

Friend here is the code for you. Use a reset css always.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{background:#999; border:1px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; float:left;}
.menu ul{list-style:none;}
.menu li{float:left;}
.menu a{font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; color:#dcdcdc; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; line-height:40px;}
.menu a:hover{font-family:Calibri; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; color:#000; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; line-height:40px;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

> **Use a reset.css file**